# Reaction force due to revolver

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

We all know that when we stand on a weighing machine, what we actually get to see on the machine is the normal reaction force exerted on us.If i choose to hold a revolver while standing on such a machine and pull the trigger and actually shoot a bullet upwards, will the reading on the weighing machine change even for a second due to the gun`s recoil?It would have been fun trying out, had i had a licensed revolver!

Comment: Why not try it out with an object other than a gun? Hold something in your hand and then check the scale when you throw it upward. Let us know what happened.

Comment: Instantaneous momentum of the system should be conserved so you can consider that.

Comment: @fielder - momentum isn't conserved for things attached to the ground. The earth can absorb or emit momentum as needed. Hit a ball on a wall for example, and total momentum changes drastically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a very good question!

Before we answer it, please however have in mind that shooting a projectile into air is dangerous and should not be done without proper precautions.

The weighting machine reading depends on force acting on it, in this case it is our weight.

Finally to properly answer the question, the reasoning is as follows:
When we shoot a revolver, such that the projectile exits the barrel with non zero velocity, by conservation of momentum in gun - bullet system, the gun has to move with opposite momentum such that:

$$\vec p_{bullet}+\vec p_{gun}=\vec 0$$

Note however that ideally we would like to control the gun to maintain it as static as possible. Thus we are acting on it with a force that is 'provided' by our hands.
However by Newton 3rd Law the reaction force is acting on our hands.

Since we are not interested in most advantageous position to maintain control, the simplified model will work for us just as well.

Let the model consist of bullet and body 'glued' to a gun as in a picture:[image]

As stated earlier by conservation of momentum:
$$m_{bullet}\vec v_0 = -M\vec v_{B}$$
If our motion was not constrained, we would be moving (ideally) with non zero velocity. However in our line of motion are the weight and the surface. They change our momentum to zero. If momentum changes, the forces act on a system (in this case on us). Again by Newton 3rd Law we are acting with equal in magnitude force on a system. Long story short, the reading would be higher by amount it takes to reduce our momentum to zero divided by time.

*@Please also take into account the crucial comment made by **Solomon Slow**.*

Comment: Good answer, but note: The scale's reading does not depend only on the force. The reading is a function of force _and time_. The reading on a typical bathroom scale will approach the force acting on it over a span of one or two seconds. But a very brief pulse (e.g., as caused by the recoil of a pistol) might not show up on the dial or readout at all.

Comment: @SolomonSlow this is because the force reading is a function of displacement and in the brief impulse, there isn't enough time for the scale to displace much. Also, a bathroom scale is rather highly damped, which will absorb a lot of energy, giving an incorrect reading.

Comment: @ja72, Yes. The mechanics of a scale are a large part of the explanation of its transfer function. But, I would not call the reading on the scale "incorrect" in the case that we're talking about. If the readout does not show what you hoped it would show, that's not because of any defect in the scale. It's because you expect the scale to do something that it was not designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

> will the reading on the weighing machine change even for a second due
>   to the gun`s recoil?

Yes it will increase briefly.

When the gun fires the bullet upward it applies an upward force on the bullet. Per Newton's third law, the bullet applies an equal and opposite downward force on the gun. Since you are holding the gun, that downward force is transmitted to you and to the scale, briefly increasing the normal force applied to you and the gun by the scale, increasing the scale reading. The reverse is also true. If the gun were fired downward the scale reading would temporarily decrease.

For obvious reasons don't try it. Instead, stand on a scale holding for example, a stack if dishes. Thrust them upward (without letting go, unless you don't care about the dishes!). Watch the scale reading temporarily increase.  Next let the dishes fall in your hands. Watch the scale reading decrease.

You can even observe the scale reading increase if you begin in a crouched position and suddenly rise. Conversely, the reading will decrease if, beginning in a standing position, you abruptly drop to a crouched position.

Hope this helps.